# Cross platform mobile framework

Tags: mobile, frameworks

I am looking into building an intranet based app which can support different mobile platforms.

I have looked into phonegap, sencha touch and jquery mobile. I am confused as to how the business logic can be incorporated on the client side ? Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is just a web browser that has an access to native apis. So you can use more or less any technology that a normal web browser can interpret.

With that in mind, for a business logic you have to general options: 1) create an api somewhere on you server and just make ajax calls from you application and/or 2) use javascript. This is the only language that can be used for business logic inside phonegap (beside the native java, objective-c and etc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what about sencha touch and jquery mobile ?

Comment: jquery mobile inside phonegap does the same job as jquery does in normal browsers, e.i. it makes writing javascript code easier and faster. I'm not quite familiar with sencha touch but as I know it's a similar thing.

P.S. If you are looking a cross platform tool for creating native mobile applications I would suggest to take a look at Appcelerator as well.

Comment: Thanks Levani. I will look into Appcelerator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Out of all those mobile frameworks available, I would suggest you to go for **Sencha Touch** with **PhoneGap**. The reason I prefer Sencha Touch over Jquery Mobile is that Sencha Touch is far more smoother than JQM when it comes to page transition and navigation. Also, the extensive documentation from Sencha gives you a quick start on building mobile apps for both Android and iOS.

You may use PhoneGap if you would like to access any of the native features like Camera, Contacts etc.,

Here are some useful links:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch/
http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2
http://miamicoder.com/sencha-touch-tutorials/

Comment: @Greeniewanted I will look into sencha touch as an option too, Thank you for the tutorial links!

Comment: Any idea about dojo mobile ?